# How can I add websphere admin jars to Hudson's class path?

Tags: hudson, websphere

I try to use Hudson's Deploy Websphere plug-in to deploy my artifacts to remote websphere.

From the plug-in [documentation](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+WebSphere+Plugin), I need to do this:

The following WAS JAR files need to be placed into the Hudson class path or dropped into the %project.basedir%/WEB-INF/lib/  directory. These JAR files can be copied from the %WAS_HOME%/runtimes/ directory of your WAS server installation.

- com.ibm.ws.admin.client_6.1.0
- com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_6.1.0

I have installed hudson as a windows service, how can I add these jars to hudson's class path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Hudson's [documentation](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service):

> Changing the configuration of services
>
> The JVM launch parameters of these
> Windows services are controlled by an
> XML file hudson.xml and
> hudson-slave.xml respectively. These
> files can be found in $HUDSON_HOME and
> in the slave root directory
> respectively, after you've install
> them as Windows services.
>
> The file format should be
> self-explanatory. Tweak the arguments
> for example to give JVM a bigger
> memory.
>
> Stdout and stderr from the service
> processes go to log files in the same
> directory.

So, it appears you can manipulate the service's JVM classpath using the hudson.xml file.

HTH